# Lockscreen Widgets not showing up on device at all

Tags: swiftui, ioswidgets

What's up guys, this is the code I have, but it doesn't display the widget on the device. It just shows a little gray line for accessoryCircular. I've been trying to figure out for a while why my widget is not displaying anything.. anyone know what's happening?

```
struct testingEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

@Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    
    var body: some View {
        switch widgetFamily {
        case .accessoryCircular:
            VStack {
                Gauge(value: 0.75) {
                    Text("3/4")
                }
                .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
            }
        case .accessoryInline:
            Text("3 undone todos")
        case .accessoryRectangular:
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                    Text("Pick up the milk")
         .font(.headline)
                        .widgetAccentable()
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                    Text("Take out the trash")
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                    Text("Feed the cat")
                }
            }
            .privacySensitive()
        default:
            Text("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
```

}
[image]